# Simple.Data with Oracle

Tags: oracle, simple.data

I've created a basic console app for playing around with Simple.Data against an Oracle server.
However, when trying to open a connection I get the following error:
"No ADO Provider found."

I installed the following NuGet packages:

- Simple.Data.Core     (version 0.17.0.1)
- Simple.Data.Ado      (version 0.17.0.1)
- Simple.Data.Oracle   (version 0.17.0.0)
- Oracle Data Provier for .NET (ODP.NET) x86   (version 112.3.0)   (also tried the x64 but to
  no avail)

This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        var db = Database.OpenConnection(connectionString); // this is where I get the error
        var list = db.MyTable.All().ToList();
    }
}
```

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="user id=SomeUser;password=SomePwd;data source=MyTNS" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.112.3.0" newVersion="4.112.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And MyTNS does exist.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `providerName` attribute.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" 
         connectionString="user id=SomeUser;password=SomePwd;data source=MyTNS" 
         providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"
         />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. I still get the same error. But thank you for your answer. I'm wondering if the problem has anything to do with Simple.Data not being able to find the oracle provider assembly for some reason, even though it actually is in the build output folder along with the other assemblies.
I also want to mention that I have Oracle client 11.2.0 installed (if that is of any relevance).

Comment: OK, so I finally found the solution. @AVD is basically right. However, it must be combined with the usage of Database.OpenNamedConnection("MyConnectionString"); i.e. the one taking the name of the connection string rather than the connection string itself.

Comment: I've just been working on the provider resolution code to hopefully make this work better. Will be in a release in the next week or so.